# How to get codecov.io to post coverage reports to bitbucket pull request comments

Tags: bitbucket, bitrise, codecov

I am trying out using codecov.io with BitRise and BitBucket. I am able to get code coverage reports from my pull requests posted to CodeCov.io, but not to the bitbucket pull request comments.

I have added a codecov.yaml file to the repo, which looks like this:

```
 comment:
  layout: "reach, diff, flags, files"
  behavior: default
  require_changes: false  # if true: only post the comment if coverage changes
  require_base: no        # [yes :: must have a base report to post]
  require_head: no       # [yes :: must have a head report to post]
  branches: null
```

And I have also set up a new bitbucket user with write access to the repo, that I have also logged into codecov.io with, and I have set this user as the 'codecov bot' by editing the Team.yaml file as follows:

```
codecov:
    bot: codecovbot
```

Is there anything else I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Did you contact codecov support? As far as I know they should be the one who can tell you how to integrate codecov with bitbucket.

Comment: Are you using BitBucket cloud or server?

Answer (score 0):

You can add yml setting in your codecov.io account:

```
codecov:
    bot: codecovbot

coverage:
    status:
        project:
            default: off
        patch:
            default: off

comment:
  layout: "diff, flags, files"
  behavior: default
  require_changes: false  # if true: only post the comment if coverage changes
  require_base: no        # [yes :: must have a base report to post]
  require_head: yes       # [yes :: must have a head report to post]
  branches: null
```